Is Client-side validation in Yajra DataTables Edit and Create modals possible?
I'm trying to create a Yajra DataTable Editor that has client-side validation. The goal is to make it validate user input while actively typing within the create and edit modals text input.
Say for example, if the user were to type in non-numerical characters or invalidate the IP syntax in the primaryip field, it should show an error saying something like "Please enter a valid IP address". Right now, on the create or update button press within the modals, it will show a "The primaryip field format is invalid" which is fine, but it would be great to have client-side validation.
Here is the current Yajra DataTable I'm working with, and the server side DataTableEditor validation that works as intended already whenever the submit button is pressed.
ProxyDataTable.php:
<?php

namespace App\DataTables;

use App\Models\Proxy;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder as QueryBuilder;
use Yajra\DataTables\EloquentDataTable;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Builder as HtmlBuilder;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Button;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Column;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Editor\Editor;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Editor\Fields;
use Yajra\DataTables\Services\DataTable;

class ProxyDataTable extends DataTable
{
    /**
     * Build the DataTable class.
     *
     * @param QueryBuilder $query Results from query() method.
     */
    public function dataTable(QueryBuilder $query): EloquentDataTable
    {
        return (new EloquentDataTable($query))
            ->setRowId('id');
    }

    /**
     * Get the query source of dataTable.
     */
    public function query(Proxy $model): QueryBuilder
    {
        return $model->newQuery();
    }

    /**
     * Optional method if you want to use the html builder.
     */
    public function html(): HtmlBuilder
    {
        return $this->builder()
                    ->setTableId('proxy-table')
                    ->columns($this->getColumns())
                    ->minifiedAjax()
                    ->dom('Blfrtip')
                    ->orderBy(1)
                    ->selectStyleSingle()
                    ->editors([
                        Editor::make()
                              ->fields([
                                  Fields\Text::make('name')->label('Name'),
                                  Fields\Text::make('primaryip')->label('Primary IP'),
                                  Fields\Text::make('primaryname')->label('Primary Name'),
                                  Fields\Text::make('secondaryip')->label('Secondary IP'),
                                  Fields\Text::make('secondaryname')->label('Secondary Name')
                              ]),
                    ])
                    ->buttons([
                        Button::make('create')->editor('editor'),
                        Button::make('edit')->editor('editor'),
                        Button::make('remove')->editor('editor'),
                        Button::make('copy'),
                        Button::make('csv'),
                    ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the dataTable columns definition.
     */
    public function getColumns(): array
    {
        return [
            Column::make('id')->title('ID')
            ->width(30),
            Column::make('name')->title('Name'),
            Column::make('primaryip')->title('Primary IP'),
            Column::make('primaryname')->title('Primary Name'),
            Column::make('secondaryip')->title('Secondary IP'),
            Column::make('secondaryname')->title('Secondary Name')
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the filename for export.
     */
    protected function filename(): string
    {
        return 'Proxy_' . date('YmdHis');
    }
}


ProxyDataTableEditor.php:
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\DataTables;

use App\Models\Proxy;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Yajra\DataTables\DataTablesEditor;

class ProxyDataTableEditor extends DataTablesEditor
{
    protected $model = Proxy::class;

    /**
     * Get create action validation rules.
     */
    public function createRules(): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|max:256|unique:'.$this->resolveModel()->getTable(),
            'primaryip' => [
                'required',
                'max:50',
                'regex:/^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/'
            ],
            'primaryname' => 'required|max:64',
            'secondaryip' => [
                'required',
                'max:50',
                'regex:/^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/'
            ],
            'secondaryname' => 'required|max:64'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get edit action validation rules.
     */
    public function editRules(Model $model): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'sometimes|required|max:256|'.Rule::unique($model->getTable())->ignore($model->getKey()), // Added | before Rule::unique
            'primaryip' => [
                'sometimes',
                'required',
                'max:50',
                'regex:/^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/'
            ],
            'primaryname' => 'sometimes|required|max:64',
            'secondaryip' => [
                'sometimes',
                'required',
                'max:50',
                'regex:/^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/'
            ],
            'secondaryname' => 'sometimes|required|max:64'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get remove action validation rules.
     */
    public function removeRules(Model $model): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Event hook that is fired after `creating` and `updating` hooks, but before
     * the model is saved to the database.
     */
    public function saving(Model $model, array $data): array
    {
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Event hook that is fired after `created` and `updated` events.
     */
    public function saved(Model $model, array $data): Model
    {
        // do something after saving the model

        return $model;
    }
}


I've tried to look for where I can include some JavaScript (JQuery) to implement this functionality, however, I'm not sure where Yajra initializes the edit and create modals when the buttons are clicked. If I somehow do change the functionality of the modals, will that affect other tables in the same Laravel project?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
